# Shortcode code returns incorrect URL - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, random

I'm writing a WP shortcode to disaply random images from a path that's given by input.
[random-image pag="" class=""]
The code works nicely, but returns the correct url + the page i've put the shortcode.
Example: 
I'm currently renovating my website locally.
The actual URL is: https://localhost/z/ 
But after I've finished coding it will become https://localhost/

If I put the shortcode on /prova page ( https://localhost/z/prova/ )
the image src will show "wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/img/home/2.jpg" which is correct but if I mouse over it it shows the full path like this:
 "https://localhost/z**/prova/**wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/img/home/2.jpg" instead of "https://localhost/z/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/img/home/2.jpg"

I've tried changing the $imagesDir in
$imagesDir = get_site_url() . 'wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/img/' . esc_attr($values['pag']) .'/';
or $imagesDir = 'z/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/img/' . esc_attr($values['pag']) .'/';
or even: $imagesDir = 'https://localhost/z/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/img/' . esc_attr($values['pag']) .'/';

But all of these return with

```
// Random img 
function random_image(  $atts, $content = null ) {
    $values = shortcode_atts( array(
    'pag'       => 'home',
    'class'     => 'imgrnd',
    ), $atts );

    $imagesDir = 'wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/img/' . esc_attr($values['pag']) .'/';

    $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

    $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];

    return '<img src="' . $randomImage . '" class="' . esc_attr($values['class']) . '">';

}
add_shortcode( 'random-image', 'random_image' );
```

Comment: A simple `$imagesDir = '/wp-content/...';` doesn’t do the trick …?

Comment: @04FS Nope, it returns with nothing

Comment: What do you mean, _“it returns with nothing”_? Please be specific.

Comment: _“the image src will show "wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/img/home/2.jpg" which is correct”_ - “correct” is up for debate here. This relative URL would only be the correct one in combination with specific base URIs - with others, it won’t be.

Comment: Maybe `$imagesDir = '/z/wp-content/...';` then. It is rather unclear what the actual absolute URL of the image is, from your description. The underlying issue in any way seems to be that you are not familiar with how resolving of relative URLs actually works, so you should go read up on that somewhere.

Comment: @04FS Thanks for your helo but as i said it doesn't work, it returns nothign if i add any / before the url (ex. it works with wp-content/.. but not with /wp-content/... ).

Comment: AGAIN - what do you mean by _“it returns nothign”_? Please stop using such vague statements, and be _precise_ in describing what is actually going on! Does the `src` attribute of the image in the generated HTML code stay empty? Probably not. Is the browser not able to load the image, because the path is still wrong? (Then “it returns nothign” would be a pretty weird way to describe that.) Can you at least tell us what the actual, correct, full absolute URL to the image _would_ be?

Comment: Jezzz calm down man, I came here to ask for help and you act crazy.
I repeat once more, when i say it returns nothing, it really does! I go inspect the IMG and inside the src there's nothing! EMPTY! How do i have to say it? And how do you say probably not if I'm telling you it's like this and I don't really understand why? And you know i came here for this help!

Comment: We can only help you, if you give us enough info to make help possible in the first place.

Comment: And you keep asking me what i already wrote in the post. The full correct path should be: "https://localhost/z/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/img/home/2.jpg"

Comment: Well then it makes no sense that an image src path starting with `/z/wp-content/...` should not work.

Comment: I don't know what to say man, I really don't understand why it doesn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by changing the return output with

```
'<img src="' . '/z/' . $randomImage . '" class="' . esc_attr($values['class']) . '">';
```

But i still don't like this solution, is there a better way to fix it?